# MySQL Configuration on my.cnf

Tags: linux, mysql, database, database-administration, mysql5.5

```
[mysqld]
core-file
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
max_connections = 5000
max_user_connections = 5000
key_buffer = 1024MB
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
join_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256M
table_cache = 1024
thread_cache_size = 16K
wait_timeout = 30
connect_timeout = 15
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 512M
max_connect_errors = 10
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
low_priority_updates=1
concurrent_insert=ALWAYS
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
myisam_repair_threads=16
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 8192
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 512M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 64M
sort_buffer = 64M
read_buffer = 16M
write_buffer = 16M
```

I'm sitting on a 16 CORE 24GB RAM box and I was a little confused as to how to set the settings. I do know you set them higher with more RAM.

Is there a formal on how to correct set the values?

I'm expecting to run a very high traffic website on this box.

Answer (score 1):

The settings absolutely depend on the type of workload, and what engine your tables will be using.  If you plan on using MyISAM, the settings would be *very* different than if you're using InnoDB.

I'd recommend using Percona's configuration generator to get started.
https://tools.percona.com/